# Scrapy - Return scraped data to a function (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Is there a way to `yield` a request to a python generator, have that generator `yield` multiple functions which collect data for a particular dict, and then return that information to the original request?  Preferably doing most of this through [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html)?

Forgive me if this is a silly question, my experience with Python is somewhat limited and asynchronous programming confuses me quite a bit.

Here is a visual representation of a very similar idea related to what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image]

In this particular instance, a search request might be a `yield` from another python class.  This search request calls a particular function which would look like

```
def parse_request(self, response):
        searchparam = response.meta['apn']
        metaObject = {
            "search" : searchparam,
        }
        yield Request(self.urlOne.format(searchparam), self.searchFunctionOne, headers=self.headers, meta=metaObject)
        yield Request(self.urlTwo.format(searchparam), self.searchFunctionTwo, headers=self.headers, meta=metaObject)
        yield Request(self.urlThree.format(searchparam), self.searchFunctionThree, headers=self.headers, meta=metaObject)
```

Each of those `Request`s would go out and grab a different bit of information all pertaining to the search that was requested.  Each `searchFunction` would fill the dict with a little more info.

My main question is, how can I send that dict back to the original function that was requesting the information, without being able to `return` it after the `yield Request` statements?

The solutions I've pondered (not yet tried, out of sheer lack of knowledge to write any code that will function properly), were:

- Using something like [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)
- I got there from looking at the
  [scrapy coroutines docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/coroutines.html)
- Moving away from scrapy and scraping pages using just vanilla python with asyncio.
- Having some sort of listener be requested instead of a search function (possibly a callback instead of a listener), that watches the dict waiting to be built, checks for completion and then returns it when complete (certain conditions are met, such as all required keys existing)

There isn't enough information in the scrapy docs for ME to infer a solution, and I wasn't sure how I could make scrapy yields asynchronous when twisted is inherently asynchronous itself.

Essentially what I'd like to accomplish would be something like:

```
def parse_request(self, response):
        searchparam = response.meta['apn']
        metaObject = {
            "search" : searchparam,
        }
        finalObject = {}
        finalObject['keyOne'] = await yield Request(self.urlOne.format(searchparam), self.searchFunctionOne, headers=self.headers, meta=metaObject)
        finalObject['keyTwo'] = await yield Request(self.urlTwo.format(searchparam), self.searchFunctionTwo, headers=self.headers, meta=metaObject)
        finalObject['keyThree'] = await yield Request(self.urlThree.format(searchparam), self.searchFunctionThree, headers=self.headers, meta=metaObject)
        
        return finalObject
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance and knowledge you can provide.

Comment: There’s https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-inline-requests/. Either that (or similar alternatives), or rewriting your logic to keep the data for the following requests in `cb_kwargs` or `meta`, yield the following request from each callback, and then yield the final result when there are no more requests.

Comment: Ahh yes I was looking at inline-requests as well.  I didn't know if that was relevant to the problem I was having but I suppose based on your comment the answer would be that I can make that into a solution.  In regards to the second suggestion how can I yield the final request back to the code requesting, like `return`?  If there was a function calling `parse_request` through a `yield`, how can I return the data collected to that function?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: ”how can I yield the final request back to the code requesting“. You don’t. You run that code on the callback that handles the last response. It’s hard to wrap your head around when starting to use Scrapy; we should probably cover this better in the documentation, as it’s a common question.